# VisualBasic - View object in the listbox in ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview, listbox

I decided to program a simple application. And I need advice. I must point out that I'm a complete beginner, yesterday I started with VB ...

I have a listbox:

Code:

```
   listUzivatelu.Items.Clear ()
   listUzivatelu.Items.AddRange (databaze.VratVsechny ())
```

And I needed it to appear in the ListView:

Code:

```
             Dim TempStr (1) As String
             TempStr (0) = "1111"
             TempStr (1) = "Doe, John"
             ListView1.Items.Add (New ListViewItem (TempStr))
```

But when I write databaze.VratVsechny () so it just throws an error.

databaze.VratVsechny() returns:

Code:

```
     Public Function VratVsechny () As Product ()
         Return Vyrobek.ToArray ()

     end Function
```

I'm attach source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/btg5c66wvafo8qj/csv-zapis-a-cteni-objektu.zip

Thanks in advance for any advice on the topic.

Comment: a) `just throws an error` is not going to get you much help: WHICH error? b) `TempStr` is an array with 2 elements, for a ListView, you probably want to make them subitem(s) c) too little code to tell whats going on with `VratVsechny` because we cant see what kind of object `databaze` is

Comment: @Plutonix This is a database CSV.

Once again I would like very much but ask for help

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your project, the only problem appeared when executing this line:

```
databaze.Nacti()
```

And after digging to the method, I found that error caused by parsing "invalid" string to DateTime. Date strings in csv file appear in `date.month.year` format, when I edited csv to use `month.date.year` it parsed successfully and the program run with no error. Another alternative is to use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of Parse method. For Example:

```
Dim registrovan = DateTime.ParseExact(rozdeleno(2), "d", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"))
```

That will successfully parse your current date string in csv, because [date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) in Russian culture is `dd.mm.yy`.